# Should I refactor this, or is my confusion cause to be cautious?

Tags: c#, sql, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

This SqlCe code looks awfully strange to me:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO departments ( account_id, name) VALUES (?, ?)";
foreach(DataTable tab in dset.Tables)
{
    if (tab.TableName == "Departments")
    {
        foreach(DataRow row in tab.Rows)
        {
            Department Dept = new Department();
            if (!ret)
                ret = true;
            foreach(DataColumn column in tab.Columns)
            {

                if (column.ColumnName == "AccountID")
                {
                    Dept.AccountID = (string) row[column];
                }
                else if (column.ColumnName == "Name")
                {
                    if (!row.IsNull(column))
                        Dept.AccountName = (string) row[column];
                    else
                        Dept.AccountName = "";
                }
            }
            List.List.Add(Dept);
            . . .
            dSQL = "INSERT INTO departments ( account_id, name) VALUES ('" + Dept.AccountID + "','" + Dept.AccountName +"')";

            if (!First)
            {
                cmd.Parameters[0].Value = Dept.AccountID;
                cmd.Parameters[1].Value = Dept.AccountName;
            }

            if (First)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@account_id",Dept.AccountID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("name",Dept.AccountName);
                cmd.Prepare();
                First = false;
            }

            if (frmCentral.CancelFetchInvDataInProgress)
            {
                ret = false;
                return ret;
            }

            try
            {
                dbconn.DBCommand( cmd, dSQL, true );
            } 
            . . .

    public void DBCommand(SqlCeCommand cmd, string dynSQL, bool Silent)
    {
        SqlCeTransaction trans = GetConnection().BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Transaction = trans;
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try 
            {
                trans.Rollback();
            }
            catch (SqlCeException) 
            {
                // Handle possible exception here
            }
            MessageBox.Show("DBCommand Except 2"); // This one I haven't seen...
            WriteDBCommandException(dynSQL, ex, Silent);
        }
    }
```

My questions are:

1) Should "?" really be used in the assignment to cmd.CommandText, or should "@" be used instead?

2) One of the "cmd.Parameters.Add()"s (account_id) uses a "@" and the other (name) doesn't. Which way is right, or is the "@" optional?

3) I can't make heads or tails of why DBCommand() is written as it is - the final two args are only used if there's an exception...???

I'm tempted to radically refactor this code, because it seems so bizarre, but since I don't really understand it, that might be a recipe for disaster...

Comment: Is this SQL Server..? if so why don't you use the `@` sign when doing your Insert command vs using `?` like how Access would expect..I would refactor that code to implement using / utilizing the .Parameters.AddWithValue() Method... I would also wrap the code around a `try{} catch{}` even in the areas where you are using / trying to add the parameters.. the `?` would be equiv to `@` but that looks like DataAdapter style of coding I could be mistaken..

Comment: I would refactor some of it into a stored procedure and call that with the data.

Comment: If the code works then this would be better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you using SqlClient or OleDb?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - That's one of my questions - why is ? used instead of @? AFAIK, there's no reason for this, but I want to verify that it should be @ instead of ? before changing it. IOW: This is not my code; or to be more accurate, I didn't write it.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE and Pete: As the tag indicates, this is SqlServerCe

Comment: there is also a sql `tag as well Clay`

Comment: I think **closed as too localized** means, "We are afraid to try, and it requires too much thinking for us to understand what you are doing."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` parameter is older Access syntax.

My guess is this used to be an Access database, but someone converted it to SQL CE at some point.

Generally, SQL understands that `?` parameter, but it's better to just change that while you are in there so that it is more understood.

I'm still trying to make heads & tails of all these variables. If I get it sorted out, I'll post up compilable (sp?) code.

**EDIT:** I had to put this into a method and work out all of the RED errors to make sure I wasn't giving you something that would not compile.

I passed it your DataSet like so, with lots of comments added:

```
private bool StrangeSqlCeCode(DataSet dset) {
  const string ACCOUNT_ID = "AccountID";
  const string DEPARTMENTS = "Departments";
  const string NAME = "Name";
  const string SQL_TEXT = "INSERT INTO departments (account_id, name) VALUES (@account_id, @name)";
  bool ret = false;
  //bool First = false; (we don't need this anymore, because we initialize the SqlCeCommand correctly up front)
  using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(SQL_TEXT)) {
    // Be sure to set this to the data type of the database and size field
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@account_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    if (-1 < dset.Tables.IndexOf(DEPARTMENTS)) {
      DataTable tab = dset.Tables[DEPARTMENTS];
      foreach (DataRow row in tab.Rows) {
        // Check this much earlier. No need in doing all the rest if a Cancel has been requested
        if (!frmCentral.CancelFetchInvDataInProgress) {
          Department Dept = new Department();
          if (!ret)
            ret = true;
          // Wow! Long way about getting the data below:
          //foreach (DataColumn column in tab.Columns) {
          //  if (column.ColumnName == "AccountID") {
          //    Dept.AccountID = (string)row[column];
          //  } else if (column.ColumnName == "Name") {
          //    Dept.AccountName = !row.IsNull(column) ? row[column].ToString() : String.Empty;
          //  }
          //}
          if (-1 < tab.Columns.IndexOf(ACCOUNT_ID)) {
            Dept.AccountID = row[ACCOUNT_ID].ToString();
          }
          if (-1 < tab.Columns.IndexOf(NAME)) {
            Dept.AccountName = row[NAME].ToString();
          }
          List.List.Add(Dept);
          // This statement below is logically the same as cmd.CommandText, so just don't use it
          //string dSQL = "INSERT INTO departments ( account_id, name) VALUES ('" + Dept.AccountID + "','" + Dept.AccountName + "')";
          cmd.Parameters["@account_id"].Value = Dept.AccountID;
          cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = Dept.AccountName;
          cmd.Prepare(); // I really don't ever use this. Is it necessary? Perhaps.
          // This whole routine below is already in a Try/Catch, so this one isn't necessary
          //try {
          dbconn.DBCommand(cmd, true);
          //} catch {
          //}
        } else {
          ret = false;
          return ret;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

I wrote an overload for your DBCommand method to work with Legacy code:

```
public void DBCommand(SqlCeCommand cmd, string dynSQL, bool Silent) {
  cmd.CommandText = dynSQL;
  DBCommand(cmd, Silent);
}

public void DBCommand(SqlCeCommand cmd, bool Silent) {
  string dynSQL = cmd.CommandText;
  SqlCeTransaction trans = GetConnection().BeginTransaction();
  cmd.Transaction = trans;
  try {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    trans.Commit();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    try {
      trans.Rollback(); // I was under the impression you never needed to call this.
      // If Commit is never called, the transaction is automatically rolled back.
    } catch (SqlCeException) {
      // Handle possible exception here
    }
    MessageBox.Show("DBCommand Except 2"); // This one I haven't seen...
    //WriteDBCommandException(dynSQL, ex, Silent);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see a (+1) and a (-1) vote. As usual, no one will admit to their downvote or say why they downvoted.

Comment: It's probably the ghost of Elvis, because -- I ain't never caught a rabbit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain this article will answer some of your questions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

The second chart explains the difference between the named and positional (?) parameters (used in OleDb and ODBC).

I believe in the case where the ? is used, the @ is optional, but I'm not sure of this. If it's working, I'd say that that IS the case.

The stuff in DBCommand appears to simply be there for logging purposes. If the exection fails, it tries to do a rollback and then logs the exception with the sql command (in `dynSQL`).

Comment: Something is not working, and I don't know if this is the problem or not. I get, "there was an error parsing the query" but I don't know just where that's happening. To nip a "why don't you just step through it" response: I can't. This is an ancient-technology app with very limited tooling and debugging capabilites (VS 2003, .NET 1.1).

Comment: I think adding the @ would be prudent, then. It's clearly the norm from what I've been able to see. What is the back-end database?

Comment: Sql Server CE on a handheld.

Comment: Since you're using SqlServer CE, then replace the `(?, ?)` with `(@account_id, @name)` and add the @ to the name parameter and see if that doesn't fix your issue. I'm fairly certain SqlServer CE should be using named parameters.

Comment: I was hoping to vote for Pedro, but even though I think the codebase is better now for having swapped all the "?"s for "@<paramName>"s (and adding the "@" to the one place where it was inexplicablyl and inadvertently (I assume) omitted, I still get, "There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number, Token line offset,, Token in error,,]"

Comment: I wonder if using a column name such as "Name" could be causing this? If so (if it chokes on "Name" because name is reserved), what is the solution - encase it in braces or brackets, or...???

Comment: Yeah, try square brackets: `[name]` in the insert (not in the parameter). That might be it, but the jp2code's post seems to imply it's not needed... Unfortunately I'm not in a position to test any of this.

Comment: Unfortunately, encasing the "name" columns (there are several) in brackets caused a problem of its own, namely (no pun intended), "Invalid SQL - record ignored"

Comment: AND, replacing the "?" with "@" broke it entirely; I had to reinstate all of the "?" params (even though the code to assign the values *does* use "@"!!! Bizarre/go figure.